# Difference in Google Drive APIs?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am working on an application for which I need to **upload/download** files from the user's **Google Drive account**. I came across two documentation from Google about using Google Drive API on Android Platfrom:

1. [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android)
2. [Google Drive API Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)

I have following questions:

- What is the difference between these two options?
- What are the **advantages** and **disadvantages** of each option?
- Which is a more suitable option for Android application development?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive Android API is a native Android API which utilises the Google Play Services to communicate.

Whereas the rest API is a HTTP API - Which can be used in any platform - Web, Android, iOS. REST api is implemented using REST approach.

The Android API is an abstraction layer with certain optimisations. So your choice of API would depend on your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can please answer the 2nd and the 3rd questions?

Comment: go through the link\ https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/01/introducing-google-drive-android-api.html     and using REST api is a better option for android.

Comment: Drive API for Android is deprecated. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/sync-google-drive-files-to-apps-using-the-drive-rest-api-bidding-farewell-to-the-drive-android-api